# Realimentación a este código

Tags: wordpress

he intentado hacer el siguiente código que me muestre la lista de etiquetas que tiene cada categoría, tengo este código.

```
    <?php
    $term_id  = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $categorys  = get_term_meta($term_id, 'genero', true);
    query_posts('posts_per_page=6&category_name='.$categorys);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       if( get_the_tag_list() ){
          echo get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');
       }
    endwhile; endif; 
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Me funciona, pero quiero agregarle classes personalizadas y también imagen de la categoría.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: fijate el source de [`get_the_tag_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tag_list/#source) que usa internamente [`get_the_term_list` /  `get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/#source) ahi te va a dar una idea de cómo armar la lista y ponerle classes a cada tag, para la imagen podes combinar `$image_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true )` con `$thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );` dentro del loop custom anterior